# How should I add where condition in lambda expression

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

I know its quite easy to put where in lambda expression in below line but as I am new I am not aware.
Here in below code coupon.products has around 27000 of products and in below line I have to add where condition like

```
where p.id not in (1,2,3) 

int[] productIds = (from p in coupon.Products select p.Id).ToArray<int>();
```

**How should I add Also how should I optimize my code?**

I had tried

```
int[] productIds = (from p in coupon.Products select p.Id).ToArray<int>().Where(i => i.Id not in (1,2));
```

Tried this not working

```
            List<int> excludedItems = new List<int>();
            foreach (BasketItem item in basket.Items)
            {
                excludedItems.Add(item.Product.Id);
            }

            // int[] excluded = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

            int[] productIds = coupon.Products.Where(p => excludedItems.Contains(p.Id))
                                              .Select(p => p.Id)
                                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Add the Where before the ToArray and I think it should work.

Comment: @TamásSzabó It won't they are selecting on `Id` then calling `.Id` on it

Comment: True, the second lambda needs to be `i => i not in (1, 2)` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally `Select` first to get the `Id`s as then further operations *might* be faster. You can then use `Except` instead of `Where` and lastly call `ToArray` on it.

```
int[] excludedIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] productIds = coupon.Products.Select(p => p.Id)
                                  .Except(excludedIds)
                                  .ToArray();
```

The problem with your code comes from the following section:

```
.ToArray<int>().Where(i => i.Id not in (1,2));
```

Firstly, you call `ToArray` and then `Where`, `Where` will return an `IEnumerable` and you want an array. Secondly, you `select` on the `Id` and then try accessing that in the `Where` when you just need `i`. Lastly, you use `not in` when you want `!(new int[] { 1, 2 }).Contains(i)` although that doesn't read nicely and creating the array on each check will be expensive.

---

Per your updated question `Productcommaitems` is a `string` containing a comma separated list of integers. You need an `int[]`, you can use `Split` and `Parse` for this:

```
 int[] excludedItems = Productcommaitems.Split(',')
                                        .Select(Int32.Parse)
                                        .ToArray();
```

Or better yet just create the `excludedItems` straight away:

```
List<int> excludedItems = new List<int>();
foreach (BasketItem item in basket.Items)
{
    excludedItems.Add(item.Product.Id);
}
```

Comment: Good one to use `Except`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I also like `!Contains` as in your answer, I think it really comes down to the situation for which one will read better.

Comment: how can i convert Productcommaitems to int[] excludedIds ?

Comment: @Xtremcool I've updated my answer, in the future include all the code you are having problems with as an [MCVE] as long as they are related like in this case. If they are not related create another question.

Comment: Thanks and in case if i want IN statement instead of Not In than what should be the code? that as optimize

Comment: @Xtremcool If that's what you really wanted why not ask that in the first place? And in any case if you want `in` you already have it i.e. `excludedItems`.

Comment: For IN statement condition I had used @PatrickHofman code contain statement, I think  that code is optimize in case of IN condition

Comment: Just need to ask that instead of placing this code if I make 1 StoreProcedure and pass excluded item and recheck items in that and then after in return get matched product and then store that value in int[] productIds. Would that case will reduce my time? right now it is taking more time

Comment: I don't know did you try that?

Comment: @Xtremcool Try it yourself, if the results aren't what you expect you can always ask a new question and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use SQL-like syntax in C#, you need to add it after the `from`:

```
int[] excluded = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] productIds = (from p in coupon.Products
                    where !excluded.Contains(p.id)
                    select p.Id
                   ).ToArray();
```

Also, it is not really SQL, so `not in` is not valid. Use the C# equivalent (`!Contains`) instead.

The same when you want to use LINQ extension methods:

```
int[] excluded = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] productIds = coupon.Products.Where(p => !excluded.Contains(p.id))
                                  .Select(p => p.id)
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: how can I convert Productcommaitems to int[] excludedIds

Comment: @Xtremcool That is a string. How would that ever be an integer array?

Comment: how could in convert string to int[] without looping

Comment: Just need to ask that instead of placing this code if I make 1 StoreProcedure and pass excluded item and recheck items in that and then after in return get matched product and then store that value in int[] productIds. Would that case will reduce my time? right now it is taking more time

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] ids = coupon.Products.Where(t => !array.Contains(t.id)).Select(t => t.id).ToArray<int>();
```

Comment: That will return Products, not integers.

Comment: Also, calling `ToList()` is redundant, why convert to a `List` first, then to an `Array`, that's just wasting resources.

Comment: Creating the array on every loop is expensive, you can use negation, `!`, instead of `== false`, the `<int>` is redundant, the `ToList` is redundant and expensive and lastly it would probably be faster to `Select` then `Where` though either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C# Linq syntax like so

```
int[] filterOut = new int[] {1,2,3};

int[] productIds = coupon.Products.Where(x => !filterOut.Contains(x.Id).Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```